# Property mapping has wrong number of columns:

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-4

I'm using hibernate 4.3.7 with mysql. I'm unable to persist joda tiem in mysql. When I use this annotation 
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone"), it throws this exception

> property mapping has wrong number of columns: car.modifiedDate type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone

Entity class:

```
  @Entity
 public class Car implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 */

@Column(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false,length = 50)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Id
@XmlElement
String carId;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "CAR_NAME", length = 50)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
String carName;

/**
 */

@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
@Column(name = "DATE_CREATED")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
DateTime dateCreated;


@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
@Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
DateTime modifiedDate;
/**
 */


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="MCR_CAR_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
java.util.Set<MainCar> mainCar;

//setters and getters
 }
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be `dateCreated` and `modifiedDate` column in your Database is of type DateTime but your code is saving as  DateTime with zone. Can you try editing the `dateCreated` and `modifiedDate` type to `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime` as below:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "DATE_CREATED")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
DateTime dateCreated;


@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
DateTime modifiedDate;
```

And if you want to save DateTime with Zone, then you have to modify your `@Type` as:

```
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime",
            parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"),
                 @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "jvm")})
        @Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED")
        @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @XmlElement
        DateTime modifiedDate;
```

Comment: How to do this? 
But the time is not correct in dB. when i persist the date, the time should be 2015-09-04 10:39:30. When i look in DBm it saves 2015-09-04 06:39:30 . what's wrong?

Comment: To accept the answer, there is a tick mark below the voting section, you have to click it and it's saving default timezone "UTC", modify `parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "UTC"),
                 @Parameter(name = "javaZone", value = "jvm")})` to suit your timezone!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer.
I try it, still the same.

Comment: Do you know how to set the date to GMT+4 or UAE?

Comment: For accepting, you have to check the tick mark below voting option, you can refer other questions on SO for same and GMT and UTC are effectively the same, at least close enough for all but scientific time keeping. See the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time